# Can i show a widget or notification that user can interact with on lock screen?

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

Is it possible to show some kind of widget or notification that the user can interact with without having to unlock his phone ? such as the media player on the HTC phones [Didn't use any other brand :)]

If i'm playing a song i get the play/stop options available on the lock screen and i can use them without having to unlock the screen.

Can this be done through an app in android ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

Comment: Thanks a lot, guess i didn't use the proper key words in my search :)